# What are the rules of "Having + Verb in third form?"

Tags: verbs

I know "having + verb in the third form" indicates any task that has been completed and the event or action after that task. But can I use it to indicate something to talk about a present or future incident?
For example, are these sentences grammatically correct?

1. Having seen you, I am not happy. (Present)
2. Having lived in London, I know its climate very well. (Present)
3. Having completed the novel, I will come to see you. (Future)
   Another sentence:
   Which one is correct?
4. Eating my dinner, I will come to meet you.
5. Having had my dinner, I will come to meet you.

Comment: Three and four are odd. Pointlessly complex.

Comment: Well, 3) and 5) are basically same in structure. If one is odd, why not the other, @Xanne ?

Comment: 4) means that while you are eating your dinner, you'll meet someone.That indeed sounds odd.

Comment: are 3/5 grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Participle phrases as in 3) often take the past indefinite tense after them. Thus, it would be apt, for instance, to say "Having completed the novel, I went to see him."

Comment: What about points 1 and 2?

Comment: They look fine to me.

Comment: It would be more natural to use _When I have completed the novel_  and _When I have had my dinner_ to refer to the future.

Comment: Actually three looks okay.